# Oracle query select sum count

Tags: oracle

I have data from below query which looks like the first table below, here if you observe the results are based on count desc. I want to display the data in the form of second table and I am having trouble with the query. That is if pagetype is details,items I want to sum the count for that ID, and if pagetype is singe-item I want to leave it alone and order by all the results count desc. 
First query gist looks like below, I have many other things in it but here is a simplified version of it.

```
SELECT id, title, count(id) as count_num , pagetype
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY count(id) desc ) AS the_row 
FROM table1, table2
where  pagetype in ('details','items','single-item')
and table1.id = table2.id 
AND ct.PAGE_VIEW_DT > sysdate - 90
ORDER BY the_row


ID             Title                     Count        pagetype
--------------------------------------------------------------
33969   TITLE ONE                         523         details
33969   TITLE ONE                         494          items
198068  TITLE THREE                       400       single-item
33968   TITLE TWO                         395         details
198068  TITLE THREE                       391          items
198068  TITLE THREE                       333          items
198068  TITLE THREE                       281         details
33969   TITLE ONE                         280       single-item
33968   TITLE TWO                         270       single-item


ID             Title                     Count        pagetype
--------------------------------------------------------------
33969   TITLE ONE                        1017   details,items
198068  TITLE THREE                      1005   details,items
198068  TITLE THREE                       400   single-item
33968   TITLE TWO                         395   details
33969   TITLE ONE                         280   single-item
33968   TITLE TWO                         270   single-item
```

Comment: So, you have a Cartesian join between `table1` and `table2`, with no join condition between them? That is hard to believe. (if you did, you wouldn't be getting the results you show.) Are you missing a condition, perhaps `table1.id = table2.id`? Regardless, it is always best if you use SQL Standard join syntax; the "comma syntax" for joins, which was invented by Oracle before the standard was adopted, is strongly advised against - by Oracle itself, for the last 20 years.

Comment: Yes, i was missing a condition...

Answer (score 0):

you can use double `group by` and oracle `listagg` and oracle `decode` function like this (this query based on you data from your query):

```
with a(ID,Title,Count,pagetype) as (
-- here your data from question
select 33969,   'TITLE ONE', 523, 'details' from dual union all
select 33969,  'TITLE ONE', 494, 'items' from dual union all
select 198068,  'TITLE THREE', 400,'single-item' from dual union all
select 33968,  'TITLE TWO', 395,'details' from dual union all
select 198068,  'TITLE THREE', 391, 'items' from dual union all
select 198068,  'TITLE THREE', 333,'items' from dual union all
select 198068, 'TITLE THREE', 281,'details' from dual union all
select 33969,  'TITLE ONE', 280,'single-item' from dual union all
select 33968,  'TITLE TWO', 270,'single-item' from dual )

select id, title, sum(scount) scount, listagg(pagetype,',') WITHIN group (order by pagetype)
  from (
select id, title, sum(count) scount, pagetype
  from a 
group by id, title, pagetype
)
group by id, title, decode(pagetype,'details','tosum','items','tosum',pagetype)
order by scount desc
```

output of this query :

```
33969   TITLE ONE   1017    details,items
198068  TITLE THREE 1005    details,items
198068  TITLE THREE 400     single-item
33968   TITLE TWO   395     details
33969   TITLE ONE   280     single-item
33968   TITLE TWO   270     single-item
```

in your query it may look like this

```
with a as (
SELECT id, title, count(id) as count_num , pagetype
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY count(id) desc ) AS the_row 
FROM table1, table2
where  pagetype in ('details','items','single-item') 
AND ct.PAGE_VIEW_DT > sysdate - 90
)

select id, title, sum(scount) scount, listagg(pagetype,',') WITHIN group (order by pagetype) ptype
  from (
select id, title, sum(count_num) scount, pagetype
  from a 
group by id, title, pagetype
)
group by id, title, decode(pagetype,'details','tosum','items','tosum',pagetype)
order by scount desc
```

its double grouped because listagg concatinate in `TITLE THREE` duplicate strings like `'details,items,items'` instead of you wanted `'details,items'` thats why i'am using double `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Consider: Conditional aggregation.  Since I added a group by here the ID, Title keep things separate and I've changed the value in pagetype to be details,items when it encounters details or items, thus allowing a group by to work.  I would think a nested replace would also work allowing a group by to work as desired.

```
SELECT id, title, count(id) as count_num
     , case when pagetype in ('details','items') 
            then 'details,items' 
            else pagetype end as pagetype
    -- , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY count(id) desc ) AS the_row
FROM table1, table2
where  pagetype in ('details','items','single-item') 
AND ct.PAGE_VIEW_DT > sysdate - 90
GROUP BY  ID, Title, case when pagetype in ('details','items') 
                          then 'details,items' 
                          else pagetype end
ORDER BY --the_row
         count(ID) DESC;
```

---Attempt two after re-reading and re-reading question...
Thanks to @Анатолий Предеин for the with statement saving me some time...

```
with a(ID,Title,Count,pagetype) as (
-- here your data from question
select 33969,   'TITLE ONE', 523, 'details' from dual union all
select 33969,  'TITLE ONE', 494, 'items' from dual union all
select 198068,  'TITLE THREE', 400,'single-item' from dual union all
select 33968,  'TITLE TWO', 395,'details' from dual union all
select 198068,  'TITLE THREE', 391, 'items' from dual union all
select 198068,  'TITLE THREE', 333,'items' from dual union all
select 198068, 'TITLE THREE', 281,'details' from dual union all
select 33969,  'TITLE ONE', 280,'single-item' from dual union all
select 33968,  'TITLE TWO', 270,'single-item' from dual ),
with a(ID,Title,Count,pagetype) as (
-- here your data from question
select 33969,   'TITLE ONE', 523, 'details' from dual union all
select 33969,  'TITLE ONE', 494, 'items' from dual union all
select 198068,  'TITLE THREE', 400,'single-item' from dual union all
select 33968,  'TITLE TWO', 395,'details' from dual union all
select 198068,  'TITLE THREE', 391, 'items' from dual union all
select 198068,  'TITLE THREE', 333,'items' from dual union all
select 198068, 'TITLE THREE', 281,'details' from dual union all
select 33969,  'TITLE ONE', 280,'single-item' from dual union all
select 33968,  'TITLE TWO', 270,'single-item' from dual )

Select ID, Title
     , sum(count)
     , case when pageType in ('details','items') then 'details,items' else pagetype end as PageType
FROM a
Group by ID, Title     , case when pageType in ('details','items') then 'details,items' else pagetype end 
order by sum(count) desc
```

There is likely a simpler way by using conditional aggregration on the initial query...

something like

```
SELECT id
     , title
     , count(id) as count_num 
     , case when pagetype in ('details','items') 
            then 'details,items' 
            else pagetype end as pagetype,
FROM table1
INNER JOIN  table2
  on  table1.id = table2.id 
WHERE pagetype in ('details','items','single-item')
  AND ct.PAGE_VIEW_DT > sysdate - 90
GROUP BY ID
       , Title
       , case when pagetype in ('details','items')
              then 'details,items' 
              else pagetype end 
ORDER BY count(id) desc
```

but i'm unable to test it without the original source data not provided in the question. (and I'm not inclined to mock some up !)

Comment: xQbert, I tried using your query, but I am still getting 2 rows for the same ID how should i address that

Comment: I think it's casued by the row number.  Can we remove that and just order by count(ID) Desc?  Updated added `-- comments to exclude the_row and added count(ID) Desc`

Comment: No, I think we need to add the sum of ID's for pagetype details and items in order to get one row for the ID and that is not happening.

Comment: any idea how to achieve the sum count of the id rows? Please suggest

Comment: I've suggested a few other approaches.